# How to merge numpy arrays without creating new array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to merge two arrays to a new one. I tried np.concat and np.stack but these seem to create a new array with data from original arrays.

```
a = numpy.asarray([1,2])
b = numpy.asarray([3,4])
c = numpy.np.concatenate((a,b))
```

This way I get c = [1,2,3,4]. But when I change the numbers in c the numbers in a or b will not be changed. How can I be able to edit the same numbers using a and c in the same time? i.e. how to create a pointer to (a,b) instead of creating c as a new array.

Comment: That's simply not possible in numpy. Please explain how you think it should work?

Comment: Numpy gets a lot of its speed and efficiency from the fact that numpy arrays occupy contiguous memory which is allocated when you create the array. This means you can't simply start using more memory without creating a new memory allocation -- in other words a new array.

Comment: You cannot do that in NumPy. It may be possible with some private NumPy methods, but you shouldn't really do that. Consider thinking about an array `c` as two arrays (a,b) that are consecutive in memory. You can access elements of a or b using indexing.